# Guardar e-mail de visitantes (Newsletter) com codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc, newsletter

Bom dia pessoal, sou iniciante em PHP e em codeigniter. Preciso de uma luz, até encontrei o que eu preciso mas não em codeigniter (Pois meu site está em mvc).

Este foi o encontrado e funcionou no meu localhost https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/Ajax-PHP-MySQL-Newsletter , mas eu não tenho como usa-lo afinal não possui Model e Controllers, e nao consigo entender ainda muito bem o Model no codeigniter.

Alguem possui entendimento do assunto e pode me ajudar?

Minha intenção é receber o E-mail e Nome da pessoa por meio de um modal em bootstrap e guardar no meu banco de dados para futuros envio de e-mails a eles.

Comment: Não é so criar um form simples e depois recuperar os valores com `$this->input->post('nome');`

Comment: Não entendi @rray, se eu fizer isso eu posso jogar num banco? como?

Comment: Usa o [active record](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) do CI. Esse projeto do github nada mais é que um form, um php para manipular o `$_POST` gravar no banco e enviar por email, essa lógica vc pode fazer com o CI de forma bem facil, o css desse projeto vc pode aproveitar caso tenha gostado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

**VIEW**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.seusite.com.br/usuario/newsletter">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" required />
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
class Usuario extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct;

        /* Preferencialmente carregue esses helpers e libraries no arquivo 
           application/config/autoload.php
        */
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function newsletter() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'Nome do usuário', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'E-mail do usuário', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) { // Se os dados foram recebidos com sucesso
            $nome = $this->input->post('nome');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');

            /* Carrega a classe que trata da tabela do usuário no banco. 
               Este método pega como referência a pasta application/models.
               Se a classe a ser carregada estiver em algum subdoínio, este deve ser informado também. pe.: $this->load->model('dao/UsuarioDAO');
            */
            $this->load->model('UsuarioDAO');
            $this->UsuarioDAO->cadastrarDadosUsuario($nome, $email);

            // Busque inserir códigos de tratamentos de erros caso o banco gere algum erro.

        } else {
            // código de tratamento de erro...
        }
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
<?php
class UsuarioDAO extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct;

        /* Preferencialmente carregue no arquivo application/config/autoload.php 
           A conexão deve estar configurada no arquivo application/config/database.php
        */
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function cadastrarDadosUsuario($nome, $email) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO usuario (nome, email) VALUES (?, ?)", array($nome, $email));

        // Inserir código de tratamento de erros...
    }
}
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava... excelente Paulo ! muito obrigado!

Comment: Foi boa. Disponha! :)